# Thymleaf for Spring in IntelliJ - URI is not registered

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

My home.html file is displaying an error of URI is not registered (Settings|Languages & Frameworks|Schemas and DTDs) in IntelliJ.

The html file to include the namespace is

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

I tried to fetch external resource but this is not working

Comment: do you have the Thymeleaf plugin installed?

Comment: This seems to be working better in 2023, however the www. part of the URL seems to be important so be sure to include that.

Answer (score 17):

The error is not a problem when running the code, but IntelliJ cannot give you codecompletion for the `th:*` functions.

This is intentional by JetBrains since they specify here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/thymeleaf.html

> To be able to use the Thymeleaf support in IntelliJ IDEA, make sure that the Thymeleaf plugin is enabled. (This plugin is bundled with the IDE and enabled by default.)

and at the top of the page, it says:

> This feature is only supported in the Ultimate edition.

I have not yet found a plugin for the Community Edition that will give you Thymeleaf support, but Thymeleaf will work perfectly fine, you just won't get any help from the IDE

Comment: I found that I disabled thymeleaf plugin. :D This answer works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved issue when I added `www`.

**Before**:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
```

**After**:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the not registered uri error. But it also causes "cannot resolve" errors for e.g. "<td th:text="${userName}">". So I just ignored this uri.

Comment: This worked for me version 2023.2.5   All the warnings like "Attribute th:insert is not allowed here" are gone now.

Answer (score 2):

Go to :
File | Settings |  Plugins

click "Install Jetbrains plugin...". find Thymeleaf in the search bar, click install.

restart is required.

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry in the Ignored Schemas and DTDs section

Go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs, then add "http://www.thymeleaf.org" in Ignored Schemas and DTDs section

Answer (score 0):

Refering https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Change the line

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

to

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
```

After that click on the line and you will find a bulb

[image]

Click on that and you will find

> Fetch External Resource

option

Click on that and that should resolve the error.